# SQL - List attributes that showed up with others

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an assignment that requires me to list the actors and actresses that show up in a movie, and then the actors and actresses that have starred with them in other movies. A diagram of the database is viewable here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9teB.png

I have a query for the first part (getting the names of actors and actresses that show up in a certain movie).

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.name
FROM cast_info c
INNER JOIN name n
ON (n.id = c.person_id)
INNER JOIN title t
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
CROSS JOIN role_type r
WHERE (t.title = 'The Movie') AND (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor')
```

Could I get some assistance to help me find the actresses and actors that star with them in other movies?

Example:

```
Actors in a given movie 'The Movie': Bob, Joe, Billy 
Actors in a different movie 'Another Movie': Joe, Daniel, Frank
Actors in another different movie 'Third Movie': Billy, Susan, Theodore
```

It should return Daniel, Frank, Susan, and Theodore, because they starred in at least one movie with one of the actors in the given movie.

Comment: Why are you using cross join to role_type? Why not use inner join row_type on c.role_id=r.id?

Comment: You should post on some sample data and expected output to clarify your question.

Comment: I posted that @JaugarChang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, and your model is 3NF, so you can use trivial `IN` to solve the problem just like you described in Natural language.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.name
FROM cast_info c
INNER JOIN name n
ON (n.id = c.person_id)
INNER JOIN title t
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
INNER JOIN role_type r
ON (c.role_id = r.id)
WHERE (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor')  --  find the actresses and actors ...
AND c.movie_id IN          -- starred in at least one movie  ...
    (SELECT movie_id  
     FROM cast_info
     WHERE id in          -- with one of the actors in the given movie => Bob, Joe, Billy 
        (SELECT cc.id
         FROM cast_info cc
         INNER JOIN role_type rr
         ON (cc.role_id = rr.id)
         WHERE ( rr.role = 'actor') -- only select actors in the given movie
         AND cc.movie_id in (select id from title where title = 'The Movie') 
        )
    )
AND c.id NOT IN  -- except the actors in the given movie
        (SELECT cc.id
         FROM cast_info cc
         INNER JOIN role_type rr
         ON (cc.role_id = rr.id)
         WHERE ( rr.role = 'actor') -- only select actors in the given movie
         AND cc.movie_id in (select id from title where title = 'The Movie') 
        )
```

This easy to translate Natural language to SQL but not efficient using `IN`, you can transfer `IN` with `EXISTS`, that would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I followed through on this and it seemed to work. However, in the last two subqueries, shouldn't it be checking for both actors and actresses? When I implemented it to search for both actors and actresses in those last two WHERE clauses, I seemed to get no results.

Comment: In your example you need Bob, Joe, Billy to be get from the given movie, and you said `with one of the actors in the given movie`, so I use `rr.role = 'actor'`. If you want `actresses and actors` you could use `rr.role in ('actress', 'actor')` , don't use `(r.role = 'actress' AND r.role = 'actor')`, that's different in Englisth says `actors and actresses` and will get no results.

Answer (score 1):

So we meet again. Hopefully I can be of the same assistance as your last question. I like that you began by breaking this down into smaller parts. I would have started at the same place as you - getting all of the actors in the necessary movie. I've changed your query slightly, by selecting the persons id instead of their name so I can keep this answer a little shorter and cleaner.

```
SELECT c.person_id
FROM cast_info c
JOIN title t ON c.movie_id = t.id
JOIN role_type r ON c.role_id = r.id
WHERE t.title = 'The Movie' AND (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor');
```

*Note, I did not use distinct here because a person should not appear in this movie as an actor or actress more than once, but c.person_id is not a unique key so it would not hurt to be sure.

Then we can get all of the movies with those actors in them. We can filter to avoid the original table.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM title t
JOIN cast_info c ON c.movie_id = t.id
WHERE t.title != 'The Movie'
   AND c.person_id IN(SELECT c.person_id
                         FROM cast_info c
                         JOIN title t ON c.movie_id = t.id
                         JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
                         WHERE t.title = 'The Movie' AND (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor'))
```

Now we can pull all of the actors from all of those movies, and exclude our original actors. Here is where it is a good idea to use distinct person id. This is because Bob may star in 'The Movie'. Later, Bob did a movie with John, and another movie with John, but we don't want John to appear twice.

So, here is the final query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.person_id
FROM cast_info c
WHERE c.movie_id IN(SELECT t.id
                 FROM title t
                 JOIN cast_info c ON c.movie_id = t.id
                 WHERE t.title != 'The Movie'
                    AND c.person_id IN(SELECT c.person_id
                                      FROM cast_info c
                                      JOIN title t ON c.movie_id = t.id
                                      JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
                                      WHERE t.title = 'The Movie' AND (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor')))
   AND c.person_id NOT IN(SELECT c.person_id
                         FROM cast_info c
                         JOIN title t ON c.movie_id = t.id
                         JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
                         WHERE t.title = 'The Movie' AND (r.role = 'actress' OR r.role = 'actor'))
```

As I've said before, it's difficult to test this without data, and it's a lot of tables to make a simple SQL Fiddle, so please try these in bits like I have written them if they don't work, and let me know what may need to be tweaked.

Comment: Hello again! I really appreciate you taking your time to respond to my questions. I apologize for asking so many (I have even more than this, honestly)! My instructor rushed through SQL really fast and you won't believe the amount of people also struggling on this assignment; because nobody was finishing it, it has been postponed 3 times already (surprising?). Anyway, back on topic... I tested your query (after adding like 3 missing parentheses on the end), and it seems to return no rows. I'll let you know if I can figure out where the error lies.

Comment: Oh god sorry for missing parens. That's my fault. When is this assignment due?

Comment: Uhh... today at midnight. Don't worry too much about helping me though, I bet you have your own battles to fight!

Comment: What time is it for you? If you're in the east, you've only got 22 minutes! Also, can I ask why you cross-join the role_type table? You should be able to just do an inner join on it, but I know that was the problem last time.

Comment: Ah! I would be sooo dead if I was in the east. Luckily, I'm in the west, so that makes 3 hours and 22 minutes! The reason I used cross join on the role_type table was that in some questions I tried using an inner join on it with the... OH. I WAS USING THE PERSON_ROLE_ID INSTEAD OF THE ROLE_ID. NO WONDER I DIDN'T GET ANY RESULTS. Ok then! I'm going to be using inner joins now. :P

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Glad you caught that. I've answered each of your questions and I followed your cross-join pattern, so please update them all accordingly. I'm going to go edit them.